Is using std::expected as an input parameter an anti-pattern?
Stumbled upon this in our codebase recently
using ThingName = std::string;
using Error = std::string;
std::vector<Thing> make_things(std::expected<std::vector<ThingName>, Error> names) {
  ...
}

and it got me thinking: what the author wanted to express with code like this? Because, what is the contract of such a function? The only sane thing upon receiving an unexpected value seems to be  to bail out with error, which the original author did. There may be some edge case for some kind of function chaining, but to me this looks like an instance of do-this-and-do-the-rest-of-the-things antipattern. In any case, this is better expressed with monadic operations or straight up checking of expected values in the caller of make_things before passing it as a parameter.
Am I missing something? Is this documented bad practice or there are valid use cases for it?

Code smell probably (as bool argument), but I won't say anti-pattern. The "edge cases" seem valid usages to me.

I agree that it is strange, and that monadic design would be anyway a better approach to handle chaining.

You'd need to ask the author of that code.  I cannot think of a decent use case, but maybe the original author is smarter than me.  Did the author comment the code?  Document the function's precondition and postcondition contracts?  Can you discern why the function is written that way by how it is used in the code?

Maybe the result of an aggressive incomplete refactoring. If the input is monadic, while the output is not, something is not right; specifically for types with empty state. If the input were optional<int>, 0 and nullopt would mean different things. What's the practical difference between value().empty() and not has_value() on the input?

Unfortunately, there are no comments. The overall structure is like this
`
std::expected<ThingName, Error> get_list_of_things_from_config() { ....}
auto names = get_list_of_things_from_config();
auto things = make_things(names);
if ( things.empty() ) {
std::print("Unable to create any of things");
return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
`
The only thing make_things does is to check whether input has_value() and return an empty vector of Things in such a case.
